# Showon with nested fields?

Tags: joomla-3.4, showon

I am trying to figure out how to get the `showon` tag to work with nested fields. Could someone please look at the code below and tell me what I do wrong or if it is at all possible.

```
<field name="main"
       type="radio"
       class="btn-group btn-group-yesno"
       default="0"
       label="LABEL"
       description="DESC" >
       <option value="0">JNO</option>
       <option value="1">JYES</option>
</field>

<field name="sub"
       type="radio"
       class="btn-group btn-group-yesno"
       default="0"
       showon="main:1"
       label="LABEL"
       description="DESC">
       <option value="0">JNO</option>
       <option value="1">JYES</option>
</field>        

<field name="nested"
       type="text"
       default=""
       showon="main:1,sub:1"
       label="LABEL"
       description="DESC">
</field>
```

Comment: @Lodder Thank you for making it look a lot better!

Comment: I don't think multiple values on the `showon` attribute is possible. You'll have to create a custom form field and inject some JS to do this

Comment: Oke. Thank you for that tip! Do you think that this should be added though?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Man, although I'm not 100% sure, you should use:

```
<field name="nested"
       type="text"
       default=""
       showon="main:1[AND]sub:1"
       label="LABEL"
       description="DESC">
</field>
```

The [AND] expects both to be true. This way your nested field should work.

Comment: Yeah you are right. The thing though is that when I asked the [AND] and the [OR] function did not yet existed. But upvoting and selecting your answer as the best as it is nowadays correct and quite frankly essential.